# No new version of PDT with indigo?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

With the eclipse indigo release around the corner, I checked the download page. It does not seem to have a link to PDT. Does this mean there wont be a new PDT version anytime soon? Cant find anything in google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Eclipse for PHP Developers" package will not be released since EPP(Eclipse Packaging Project) removed it.
PDT 3.0 for Indigo itself will be released on time.

Comment: Do we know why the EPP chose to remove it?

Comment: Who was the package maintainer and what happened to them?

Answer (score 10):

Here you can find nice tutorial with screenshots how to

**Installing PDT 3 on Eclipse 3.7 Indigo**

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.0/milestones/

In short - put this url as update source http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.0/milestones/

Comment: I could only install the package when I started as **root**. That is because I installed Eclipse in `/usr/lib/eclipse/`.

Comment: You definitely rock. Works like a charm for Eclipse 3.7 Indigo on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Due to lack of a package maintainer for the Indigo release there will be no PHP (PDT) package. If you would like to install PDT into your Eclipse installtion you can do so by using the Install New Software feature from the Help Menu and installing the PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature from the Eclipse Indigo Repo >> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/php_package.php